# How to handle password alert pop up (Windows Security) on IE?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, ie

The pop up is not the traditional alert. It looks like [this pop up.](https://image.ibb.co/mRZL8o/Capture.png)
Basically Windows Authentication system.

I have tried the classical alert handling technique (`alert.sendKeys()`) 
and the one using Robot Class but not succeed.

My IE version is 11, if it's of any use.

I googled it but, can't find anything on the internet too. Any ideas?

Comment: Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert() ;
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(_user_name,_password));
driver.switchTo().defaultContent() ;

Comment: `The method authenticateUsing(UserAndPassword) is undefined for the type Alert` I am getting this.

Comment: In order to use authenticateUsing(Credential ...) you would need to down-grade selenium version to atleast 3.1. It has been removed in the current version due to compliance issues.

Comment: One method that always works is to use [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) or [SeeShell](https://a9t9.com/).

Comment: If I downgrade my IE version would it be possible?

Comment: Found a solution using AutoIt3: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=civzNtKTCD0&index=57&list=PL6flErFppaj2ArNxLyR4nQ4JV8qFc56-M